# PHP MySQLi query function parsed incorrectly

Tags: php, function, parsing, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch data from my MySQL database and display it on a simple webpage.
However when i add the PHP code to the .html file it almost looks like the code isn't parsed as PHP.
The code below connects to the db (which works), I enter a query and then fetch the results.
However given the output it almost looks like the `->` in `$conn->query($query)` is enterpreted as `?>`

The page resulting from the code below shows these three lines of text:

```
 query($query)) {while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {echo ' 

'.$row['Title'].'

';>$result->free();}else"fail";}?>
```

Which is in accordance to the format i want, but obviously not what intended.
However i get the same resulting page from this code when i remove everything from the second line till `$conn->`.
Which gives me the impression that the code followed by `$conn->` isn't read as PHP code at all.
I think it's also important to note that i don't have this problem in a different part of my page, i.e. creating a database connection works fine and code followed by the query is parsed as i would expect.

Is my assumption correct and how can i counter this? Or have a missed something obvious causing this error?

```
<div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "marvin";
    $dbname = "blogpostdb";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts"; 

    if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div class="blog-post"> 
              <h2 class="blog-post-title">'. $row['Title'] .'</h2></div>';
        }
    $result->free();
    }
    else{
    echo "fail";
    }
    ?>
    </div><!-- /.blog-main -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the extension from `.html` to `.php`.
Files with the `.html` extension won't parse `PHP`, unless the webserver is configured to do so.